# Should I use packages when writing a class

Tags: best-practices, documentclass-writing

I am trying to write a class based on the `book` class (a thesis class for my department).

My question is: is it bad for some reason (or, is it *considered* bad) to use packages in the class files instead of more primitive TeX / LaTeX commands? For example, should I use the `geometry` package or the relevant primitive commands?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In my opinion it is very good style to include packages. Developing an own class and loading packages via `\RequirePackage` may hide a lot of stuff irrelevant to users, especially to newbies.

It makes no sense to include the plain macros from style files. Any change or bugfix in the underlying style would need to be included manually in your class as well, so it could be a lot of work.